Bounds for C# Generic Random Array Generator
I have written this block of code, in an attempt to create a generic random array generator (quite an interesting approach, if I must say so myself)
public unsafe class RandomArray<T> : DynamicArray<T> where T : INumber<T> {

    Type _type;
    Random _r;
    T _min;
    T _max;
    int _type_size;
    T _MaxValue;
    T _MinValue;
    
    private void init(int capacity) {
        _MaxValue = (T)typeof(T).GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(null);
        _MinValue = (T)typeof(T).GetField("MinValue").GetValue(null);
        // T ratio = T
        // _MaxValue & _MinValue allow us to determine the ratio
        _r = new Random();
        generate(capacity);
        _size = capacity;
    }
    
    private void generate(int capacity) {
        // take into account _min & _max
        byte[] b = new byte[capacity*_type_size+1];
        _r.NextBytes(b);
        fixed (byte* ptr_b = b) {
            T* t = (T*)ptr_b;
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                _data[i] = *(t+i);
            }
        };
    }
    
    public RandomArray(int capacity, T min, T max) : base(capacity+1) {
        _type_size = Marshal.SizeOf(min);
        _type = min.GetType();
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
        init(capacity);
    }

}

The code is a combination of concepts taken from the following sources:
To interpret bytes as generic type T:
Converting random bytes to integers within a specified range
To get the MinValue/MaxValue of a Generic primitive numeric type:
How do I get the max and min value of a generic number type in c#
However, the problem that I face is that I cannot seem to come up with a mechanism to set the bounds of the min & max elements/limit the range of the random numbers generated because of some complications related to casting.
What would be the simplest technique to mimic:
_min + (*(t+i) / ratio);
where ratio would be computed as (_MaxValue - _MinValue) / (_max - _min)
It's obvious that _MaxValue - _MinValue will be type overflow, outside the bounds of the generic T, so I have tried using BigIntegersto do this, but I can't figure out exactly how this should work.
The problem is that I can't figure out how I would cast the BigInteger result back to a generic type T as I have done in most the body of the code.
How would I handle the case of calculating the ratio so that it is well defined given the complications that arise from type casting?

converting a bunch of random bits to a value in a specific (non-power-of-two) range is somewhat difficult if you want to ensure equal probability. Rejection sampling is the easy and safe, but possibly slow, option. Eric Lipperts series on Fixing Random might be of interest if you want details.

@JonasH Thanx for the link to this series! I'll definitely check it out, but my problem here is not so much related to building a statistically well-behaved PRNG (though this would be a long term goal) but more to do with making it "as generic as possible" so that it is still compatible with the built-in types. Any suggestions on doing that in a better way as the above demo?

For the min/max part: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79004936/23354 - you can just use where T : INumber<T>, IMinMaxValue<T> and then access T.MinValue and T.MaxValue directly

@MarcGravell OK, That's actually a pretty cool simplification to the above approach! Thanx!

I have not used generic math much, but I have some difficulty imagining how it would be possible to do for all INumber-types. If you just want to convert bits you might want the unmanaged restriction, just be careful with special and invalid floating point values.

@JonasH As the demo code stands, I can do RandomArray<int>, RandomArray<float>, RandomArray<double>, etc ... but to specify range bounds for client as upper/lower limits for random, I would have to project to the target interval (min, max). Is there any other way that you would suggest I could achieve this in the generic context, even if I would have to abandon some of the current implementation details? I'm not really sure why I would want to concern myself with unmanaged restrictions, though?

I am yet never used Random.Next  parametersless overload, because I always need value in the range. To generate salt or something like random bytes I'd use crypto service. If min/max is the problem, just request those as parameters.

@Sinatr, that's a minor detail, I'm not so concerned with that. Unless, what you're suggesting is that I can pass in a generic min/max to the Random() constructor? but, see, I'm using the random instance to create bytes. The bytes are re-interpreted as T in the fixed unsafe context within the loop, copying the bytes over in chunks of sizeof(T). I think you get what I'm asking, but I don't know if it's possible to just pass in T min/max as args for Random() => would I still be able to use this with _r.NextBytes(b)?

For int/float/double you could use an unmanaged restriction instead. The real question is how you handle some weird custom number format, say a quaternion, or my custom format that represents values as an sequence of 1-bits of arbitrary length. I'm not sure an INumber even have to be countable, and can you even represent a random value from an uncountable set?

@JonasH I mean, you have a point. I guess it won't be compatible with all custom number types, but as long as I can get it to work with built-in types, it would definitely suffice for my needs. The real question is, how to get it to work, so that I can accept range input & internally use that to actually produce values in range. How would I even go about if, say, I left that to the client? in other, how would the client code go about projecting the produced values in the array to desired range? Solving that problem would definitely hint in the direction of what I'm trying to achieve with this.

If you only need to support built in types it will probably be easiest to just check the type and provide different implementations for each, or just avoid generics and supply multiple different methods instead. That should let you use Next/NextInt64 /NextDouble to get values in the correct range.

I did that, initially, i.e. as you mentioned, to check the type & use multiple methods for the built-ins, but it just felt repetitive, which is why I tried the above instead, just leading me here instead. I thought this would be a concepts that somebody else would have tried at some point, but I can't find exact match on SO

To change type of BigInteger is not straight forward.
I would suggest using Convert.ChangeType method, but it won't accept BigInteger, as it does not implement IConvertible.
However, BigInteger has casts to numeric types, so I would pick big numeric type (to prevent any information loss), let's use decimal. When BigInteger is cast to decimal, then we can use mentioned method Convert.ChangeType.
Here's sample code:
Console.WriteLine(Get<int>());
Console.WriteLine(Get<long>());
Console.WriteLine(Get<decimal>());

T Get<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    BigInteger b = 1;
    var t = (T)Convert.ChangeType((decimal)b, typeof(T));
    return t;
}

UPDATE
For the other way around (converting to BigInteger) here's code example:
BigInteger GetBigInt<T>(T input) where T : struct
{
    BigInteger t = Convert.ToInt64(input);
    return t;
}


Hi, @Michal. Thanx for the suggestion! Perhaps, due to the wording of the problem is not so clear. What the above code does, is that the byte array is copied over to an underlying T[] array, each group of sizeof(T) bytes being re-interpreted as a T type object. So, the problem isn't really that I can't cast back to T, the problem is more specifically, that I cannot subtract _MaxValue & _MinValue because subtraction isn't defined for T, so basically, I tried creating an BigInteger object from _MaxValue & _MinValue so that I can indeed subtract, but I don;t know how to cast T type to BigInteger

So what I want to do is something more in line with var Max = (BigInteger) Convert.ChangeType(_MaxValue, typeof(BigInteger)); & the same for _MinValue. I just tried this & it seems most promising but I get the following Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Numerics.BigInteger which makes sense, but I don't know a way around this problem

Moreover, if I do manage to subtract _MaxValue & _MinValue by first casting to strings & then creating BigIntegers from their string represetations, it will only solve my situation in case the RandomArray type parameter T is compatible with BigInteger. Every approach seems to lead to a cul-de-sac in one way or another

@LambdadotJoburg Please see, if update solves your problem.

not exactly. It does demonstrate how to convert BigInteger to int vice versa, but since I want this to be "as generic as possible" the same won't work if the type parameter is a float/double. I thought about using BigRational/BigDecimal but that would require two different implementations for the same. I guess the problem that I'm describing is to try & keep the code minimal/re-usable as much as possible. If I have to change some of the implementation details to make it work, that should be fine, but I'd like to keep it as close as possible to the original

@LambdadotJoburg You can use my methods with decimal and float as well, as presented in examples.

Are you suggesting that for converting decimal/double/float to BigInteger, I should first convert to Int64 & then to BigInteger?

@LambdadotJoburg Yes

Okay, but this leaves me with the problem that the generator will discard precision, so that I cannot produce values in a sub-1 range, for example, if client would like to generate random floats [0.5, 0.6] for example. Unless, there is another technique like _MaxValue - _MinValue / _max - _min to scale the result number in the desired range. Hence I suggested using BigDecimal? what would be your take on that?

Moreover, doing this BigInteger _MaxValue = GetBigInt<float>(float.MaxValue); leads to Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow because of first casting to Int64

@LambdadotJoburg You know what integer is? It is number without precision. I can't imagine how possibly could you use integer without loosing precision? Just go with appropriate data type, instead of riddling me impossible

lol, I must admit. This question does seem impossible, which is why I came to stackoverflow for help. Sorry => not trying to "catch you out" ... just seeking answers/possible ways of solving my problem. You're probably right that it's best to stick to "appropriate data types" but I'd like to have seen if there is a way to do this kind of problem in a generic way! I guess this finally closes the topic that there's no real way of doing this! But I hate giving up on the idea.
